# Yii - overwriting $content

Tags: php, templates, view, yii, frameworks

As far as I noticed seeking across the internet, there's no nice&smooth method for template inheritance in Yii, but I'm wondering if there's a nice method to at least overwrite $content in a template. Basically, I'm trying to avoid something like this:

```
// Let's say that I have a website with a nice layout and I created a "support" module and in its main theme I want to add a nice heading and some activity status under the $content

// modules/support/templates/main.php

$content = '<div id="someCoolHeader">lorem ipsum</div>'.$content.'<div id="supportAvailability">'.isSuportActive().'</div>';

require_once(CWebApplication::getViewPath().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'main.php');
```

How should it get done right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to templating. Layouts can be customised to your needs very much. Have a look at Yii definitive guide topic. Also [this](http://www.google.mv/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.larryullman.com%2F2012%2F05%2F16%2Fworking-with-layouts-in-yii%2F&ei=7b1dU63oAo6UiQfGjYGgBQ&usg=AFQjCNGvQuyHTvZHp1eJxPNTs8-kmW4BNQ&bvm=bv.65397613,d.aGc)